# dotnetnuke, survey module and module development

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to develop a module and using the how-to guide that dnn provides along with the survey module. In the tut they reference code behind files but when I downloaded the zip file off their site I am not seeing any code-behind files. Does anyone know if I downloaded the right package? I got it here: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-Survey.aspx

And if I dl'd the right package why is there no code behinds.

Also, anyone recommend any good dotnetnuke module tutorials?

Comment: The button row is context sensitive. Is the button not there when a project is selected in the solution explorer?

Comment: You know it actually is there. I downloaded the Dotnetnuke survey module and I guess it just doesn't have any code-behind files. It is supposed to according to the DotnetNuke module development guide. Do you know what the issue is with that? Here is where I downloaded the survey module. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-Survey.aspx

Comment: No idea about DNN survey module. Perhaps time to ask another question about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DotNetNuke Survey is hosted in Codeplex:

http://dnnsurvey.codeplex.com/

You can find the latest **[source package](http://dnnsurvey.codeplex.com/releases)** there. Module pages in www.dotnetnuke.com are not always up-to-date.

I think that the best DNN module development tutorials are still found in printed books and their code supplements, although they won't cover the latest features (No books on DNN6 yet).

I would recommend [Professional DotNetNuke Module Programming](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-DotNetNuke-Module-Programming.productCd-0470171162.html) by [Mitchel Sellers](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/). It is somewhat dated (2009), but still a good reference. See [review](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/387/Review-Professional-DotNetNuke-Module-Programming).

Other books that cover module development, in addition to DNN administration, are:

- [Building Websites with DotNetNuke 5](http://www.packtpub.com/building-websites-with-dotnetnuke-5/book) by [Ian Lackey](http://www.digitalsnap.net/) and
  [Michael Washington](http://adefwebserver.com/). ([Review](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/589/Book-Review-Building-Websites-with-DotNetNuke-5)).
- [Professional DotNetNuke 5: Open Source Web Application Framework for ASP.NET](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-DotNetNuke-5-Open-Source-Web-Application-Framework-for-ASP-NET.productCd-0470438703.html). ([Review](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/356/Book-Review-Professional-DotNetNuke-5-by-Wrox))

Comment: The modules on DotNetNuke.com are indeed up to date. They are synchronized with Codeplex every 24 hours.  This synchronization is automated.  The source code downloads would currently require you to download them directly from Codeplex though.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Nevertheless, a few months ago I ran into trouble with the Forum module, and it turned out that there was, and still is, a newer stable release on  [CodePlex](http://dnnforum.codeplex.com/releases) than on [dotnetnuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-Forums.aspx). I guess the problem was that google pointed to an old module home page.